# genes significantly different compared to other groups

Tags: r, genetics, heatmap

I am trying to compare genes that differ significantly between groups and only plot them in the heatmap. I am using R and its libraries ComplexHeatmap and cirlize.

The sample of the data that I have looks like this:

```
geneid  T1_G1   T2_G1   T3_G2   T4_G2   T5_G3   T6_G3   T7_G4   T8_G4   T9_G4   T10_G5  T11_G5  T12_G5  T13_G6  T14_G6  T15_G6  T16_G7  T17_G7  T18_G7
ENSRNOG00000000012  0.95    0.54    1.91    1.77    0.97    1.17    6.51    1.23    1.67    2.22    0.21    0.00    0.96    1.59    0.51    1.85    1.23    1.19
ENSRNOG00000000021  3.68    10.60   12.99   12.45   10.26   9.52    7.12    5.50    3.24    5.99    8.49    8.54    10.01   8.06    6.53    8.00    6.69    4.04
ENSRNOG00000000024  3.10    3.28    5.10    4.38    2.93    4.62    3.02    2.00    2.47    3.43    1.71    1.01    2.83    3.20    1.66    1.55    1.87    3.04
ENSRNOG00000000033  4.22    6.78    5.06    4.04    3.45    3.36    3.75    3.38    1.91    2.49    1.89    3.08    2.67    3.55    2.26    1.93    2.37    2.63
ENSRNOG00000000034  1.38    2.10    2.00    1.14    1.33    0.66    1.37    0.50    0.64    0.83    0.53    0.93    0.59    0.53    1.02    0.43    0.26    0.79
ENSRNOG00000000040  29.29   30.19   41.04   23.52   50.36   29.37   37.06   28.12   21.45   16.02   13.98   26.39   8.77    18.35   18.49   8.02    15.85   6.42
ENSRNOG00000000041  3.54    6.75    10.15   7.06    11.30   8.54    11.88   8.11    8.21    12.01   8.55    19.24   10.64   10.97   8.59    7.56    5.70    10.38
ENSRNOG00000000042  14.74   18.19   21.13   26.34   15.70   13.71   6.68    7.50    7.08    6.14    7.61    7.01    7.20    6.45    6.43    4.30    4.77    5.75
ENSRNOG00000000043  31.46   35.38   59.19   45.97   89.37   68.54   83.48   106.81  89.80   96.49   109.34  96.37   85.21   74.94   67.16   74.61   50.99   56.17
ENSRNOG00000000044  8.28    9.22    15.80   15.25   19.00   14.54   16.37   12.10   14.19   21.22   22.13   25.20   18.34   16.34   18.33   12.91   11.46   15.60
ENSRNOG00000000047  4.11    5.40    3.12    2.31    1.14    2.60    1.57    1.13    0.52    3.28    2.03    2.08    4.72    2.55    2.87    3.28    1.98    4.46
ENSRNOG00000000048  9.63    12.16   13.91   13.07   15.51   12.02   12.18   15.16   11.41   14.62   18.21   17.78   14.33   13.32   11.94   12.13   9.36    11.15
ENSRNOG00000000054  3.14    3.33    4.50    5.83    4.81    4.55    2.12    1.59    1.25    1.39    0.29    0.68    0.78    1.15    0.99    1.44    0.75    0.72
ENSRNOG00000000062  11.58   15.20   18.43   12.95   20.22   13.65   14.67   11.68   10.64   11.55   10.09   13.27   10.09   7.53    8.82    7.91    7.94    8.85
ENSRNOG00000000064  24.78   35.97   32.71   29.26   28.71   38.77   30.77   14.54   17.31   12.21   13.56   22.28   12.47   18.54   19.87   7.94    15.60   18.48
ENSRNOG00000000066  8.23    9.21    17.55   13.38   17.87   13.86   17.45   6.30    10.65   12.04   12.45   15.30   6.68    7.50    4.82    5.08    4.52    6.19
ENSRNOG00000000068  6.40    11.28   10.08   10.87   12.00   12.79   10.58   8.92    8.94    11.49   9.83    14.27   8.49    9.57    9.66    7.98    6.86    9.80
ENSRNOG00000000070  0.99    2.76    3.45    4.17    3.51    3.96    2.08    1.99    2.25    3.29    2.64    5.79    3.99    3.80    2.25    2.19    2.76    3.70
ENSRNOG00000000073  3.11    7.69    5.19    8.02    3.97    1.27    1.63    2.34    1.09    2.41    3.12    3.16    3.81    3.29    6.07    2.81    2.33    2.89
ENSRNOG00000000075  5.74    6.74    6.35    6.99    5.23    5.98    3.74    4.49    3.40    1.75    3.21    1.85    2.66    2.25    2.89    1.54    2.27    2.58
ENSRNOG00000000081  31.61   24.51   36.65   32.37   62.87   45.56   50.07   54.69   63.10   28.46   72.45   48.81   22.39   20.78   25.82   18.38   15.39   26.27
ENSRNOG00000000082  16.20   13.84   17.36   16.86   16.41   18.52   9.09    10.54   14.75   11.82   15.07   12.99   15.71   11.88   17.02   8.60    8.79    17.04
ENSRNOG00000000091  0.37    1.04    1.06    0.95    0.86    0.79    1.09    0.27    0.46    1.60    1.74    2.58    2.48    3.20    2.49    1.62    2.32    3.16
ENSRNOG00000000095  11.49   9.79    10.87   10.31   12.36   16.61   6.90    9.62    11.47   11.15   10.75   11.33   7.57    6.98    8.19    6.35    5.53    5.97
ENSRNOG00000000096  2.04    1.45    2.38    1.54    2.31    1.81    2.38    1.75    2.37    1.40    1.75    3.79    3.68    2.39    2.62    2.54    2.19    0.73
ENSRNOG00000000098  4.16    4.50    10.79   10.03   8.92    11.94   8.86    8.68    15.80   15.86   10.64   16.07   10.13   14.78   13.67   6.93    8.11    13.56
ENSRNOG00000000104  4.96    6.15    5.92    4.18    3.45    6.23    3.33    1.50    1.48    1.31    2.00    2.57    2.05    1.81    2.22    1.27    1.62    1.49
ENSRNOG00000000105  1.37    2.70    1.57    1.36    1.60    0.96    1.96    1.39    1.86    0.61    0.69    0.89    0.61    0.73    0.54    1.03    0.52    0.50
ENSRNOG00000000108  8.07    9.43    12.02   11.93   14.04   13.54   3.93    7.11    5.22    4.27    5.08    5.09    2.40    5.40    4.25    1.85    4.11    2.72
ENSRNOG00000000111  0.94    3.22    1.89    4.66    5.28    1.16    2.47    2.43    0.66    2.19    3.24    2.15    1.50    0.99    0.95    1.39    2.59    0.00
ENSRNOG00000000112  3.29    3.95    4.84    2.24    4.76    3.98    3.17    2.34    3.07    3.32    3.07    3.84    2.50    3.18    3.44    2.72    2.30    2.93
ENSRNOG00000000121  2.39    3.18    5.08    4.45    4.70    5.21    3.68    3.47    3.86    4.99    3.77    6.97    4.14    5.29    4.96    3.00    3.59    7.80
ENSRNOG00000000122  16.52   16.39   23.00   18.11   23.83   19.65   18.21   18.73   15.39   18.30   19.29   20.02   11.00   12.37   10.61   10.38   13.97   18.42
ENSRNOG00000000123  0.93    3.60    2.69    3.10    3.69    2.96    2.05    1.68    1.68    2.59    2.79    3.10    3.68    2.92    2.07    1.79    1.99    2.27
ENSRNOG00000000127  3.22    5.25    6.97    7.42    7.43    6.55    7.71    10.45   8.38    12.44   17.79   15.49   9.95    12.67   12.68   8.82    8.49    10.84
ENSRNOG00000000129  3.69    4.21    7.15    6.62    11.40   4.97    3.62    4.91    3.66    13.26   7.57    11.40   17.25   13.91   12.18   13.79   9.25    10.96
ENSRNOG00000000130  15.07   18.74   25.82   24.71   25.67   30.95   21.94   8.57    14.75   23.00   14.97   29.36   20.81   29.35   35.73   26.36   25.24   30.48
ENSRNOG00000000133  8.69    7.69    7.20    8.15    7.64    8.47    6.77    6.96    4.40    7.89    4.90    5.93    4.21    5.43    5.40    3.80    2.27    3.62
ENSRNOG00000000138  0.13    0.73    0.77    0.26    1.45    0.65    2.10    2.00    0.73    5.04    3.70    2.88    2.62    2.93    3.13    4.21    3.08    2.16
ENSRNOG00000000142  4.28    8.94    6.55    1.50    0.82    1.09    3.14    1.67    1.35    1.38    0.63    0.49    3.44    2.98    2.87    1.70    2.49    2.30
ENSRNOG00000000145  6.23    10.36   10.85   10.56   10.93   8.47    7.36    6.36    3.06    4.74    4.05    3.83    5.00    5.26    4.71    6.14    5.47    3.79
ENSRNOG00000000150  4.82    5.63    7.72    5.96    6.02    8.14    5.44    6.37    5.05    3.54    5.70    5.13    2.58    3.98    5.04    2.89    4.40    5.70
ENSRNOG00000000151  5.19    5.92    14.02   7.38    13.48   13.07   22.34   27.45   21.37   59.83   50.84   43.00   40.86   38.61   26.76   46.09   31.50   35.61
ENSRNOG00000000155  6.51    8.13    16.14   12.46   11.93   11.71   10.42   8.40    10.82   12.96   13.72   10.72   13.79   12.10   14.30   8.51    7.91    10.62
ENSRNOG00000000156  8.43    9.86    12.92   4.47    2.30    2.55    2.57    1.07    1.22    0.45    0.51    0.13    0.19    0.24    0.21    0.26    0.09    0.36
ENSRNOG00000000157  1.81    3.74    3.63    3.20    3.34    2.97    3.99    1.89    2.77    3.74    3.04    5.91    4.03    4.02    6.51    2.16    1.91    3.34
ENSRNOG00000000161  2.21    2.38    3.56    2.88    2.50    3.47    1.06    1.74    2.74    1.33    2.74    2.40    3.47    2.87    3.51    2.74    1.40    2.67
ENSRNOG00000000164  8.27    15.04   17.60   18.71   10.94   20.50   6.38    8.51    15.71   6.21    14.01   8.46    7.21    7.95    10.08   3.30    3.69    7.26
ENSRNOG00000000165  1.28    1.82    2.20    1.93    1.22    0.61    0.14    0.56    0.37    0.67    0.63    0.66    20.97   23.92   33.58   22.27   19.16   28.38
ENSRNOG00000000166  9.14    9.17    10.25   8.29    6.83    10.19   2.56    4.09    2.89    5.47    3.56    3.71    8.16    7.85    7.10    5.74    6.31    11.38
ENSRNOG00000000167  1.55    2.95    1.94    1.92    1.58    1.90    0.95    0.67    0.36    0.00    0.56    0.98    1.87    2.57    2.98    1.34    0.60    2.97
ENSRNOG00000000168  1.14    1.90    4.65    2.60    1.43    1.51    0.92    1.25    0.74    0.54    0.15    0.00    0.43    0.15    1.07    0.14    0.41    0.34
ENSRNOG00000000169  2.31    2.63    4.53    4.17    3.44    4.04    2.52    2.52    1.86    3.16    2.75    2.70    2.10    1.94    1.77    1.14    1.55    1.26
ENSRNOG00000000170  0.72    1.42    1.81    1.64    1.14    1.23    0.97    0.67    0.34    0.75    0.79    0.98    0.88    0.79    1.26    0.46    0.14    0.63
ENSRNOG00000000172  0.67    0.16    0.67    1.06    0.29    0.18    1.42    0.92    1.00    1.32    0.61    1.95    1.08    1.37    3.74    0.91    1.18    2.28
ENSRNOG00000000175  19.25   22.25   25.26   14.49   30.24   16.31   16.58   28.53   22.60   15.64   18.63   21.76   10.24   8.79    6.64    6.05    5.71    6.31
ENSRNOG00000000177  1.13    1.45    0.85    0.35    0.29    0.35    0.30    0.36    0.20    0.44    0.48    0.21    0.10    0.16    0.31    0.11    0.00    0.18
ENSRNOG00000000185  4.57    6.96    5.15    7.54    4.86    7.73    9.81    3.69    2.40    9.44    5.74    9.28    6.47    8.76    9.69    5.39    7.60    8.39
ENSRNOG00000000186  2.79    5.62    5.37    3.71    2.84    5.80    4.28    0.55    1.20    3.32    2.58    5.54    3.47    4.18    2.08    3.18    2.51    2.95
ENSRNOG00000000190  10.71   18.28   17.51   11.66   14.94   11.06   13.69   14.16   13.05   15.00   14.45   14.99   13.37   12.92   14.84   9.95    8.79    12.16
ENSRNOG00000000195  0.88    0.00    1.28    1.25    0.62    0.37    0.00    0.31    0.00    0.47    0.26    1.39    0.00    0.75    0.22    0.30    0.37    0.88
ENSRNOG00000000204  28.11   34.12   38.86   24.49   27.76   26.26   19.65   17.07   19.67   17.06   23.09   18.05   18.74   17.42   20.26   12.78   15.09   20.08
ENSRNOG00000000219  7.51    9.10    10.50   9.75    9.46    8.21    5.26    4.67    6.61    8.33    8.77    4.37    6.38    6.13    4.01    4.70    4.59    5.14
ENSRNOG00000000221  1.45    2.48    2.47    2.33    2.37    2.14    1.91    2.16    1.62    2.25    2.12    1.21    2.74    2.89    2.51    2.23    1.51    3.48
ENSRNOG00000000230  13.45   16.40   18.85   19.84   25.73   25.18   20.11   17.50   20.38   35.88   31.67   39.19   29.69   34.19   43.78   24.82   22.23   27.11
ENSRNOG00000000231  4.02    3.32    6.39    1.20    2.55    1.19    2.62    1.97    0.58    1.29    0.60    0.00    1.24    1.10    1.37    1.77    1.29    1.24
ENSRNOG00000000236  40.64   47.83   62.15   47.56   55.38   49.16   37.15   37.65   29.02   43.96   43.49   33.56   42.05   37.01   41.79   33.85   24.73   36.57
ENSRNOG00000019892  37.83   30.42   42.78   29.86   64.72   32.34   47.74   43.24   35.07   24.11   22.68   26.35   32.77   27.70   23.18   26.43   21.21   19.75
ENSRNOG00000019895  5.08    14.97   7.00    6.68    5.83    8.32    3.06    7.53    6.11    3.94    1.64    2.42    10.60   9.39    12.07   1.75    3.65    2.81
ENSRNOG00000019900  8.14    11.78   11.80   12.78   11.64   9.86    6.26    5.18    4.24    4.89    3.45    4.99    4.78    5.82    6.82    3.01    2.66    3.89
ENSRNOG00000019908  12.57   12.81   11.69   10.00   10.99   13.25   9.44    9.28    14.43   18.78   12.36   22.55   11.19   12.32   11.89   7.31    8.84    14.88
ENSRNOG00000019913  10.17   11.86   10.85   9.85    12.47   10.24   11.00   14.28   10.92   11.64   10.27   8.97    9.94    11.70   9.93    7.51    7.83    10.59
ENSRNOG00000019914  1.19    1.06    2.79    2.96    8.25    4.08    13.53   9.43    9.64    15.41   12.10   13.93   18.55   25.36   19.80   17.87   14.95   14.73
ENSRNOG00000019915  27.98   24.55   26.30   17.84   30.39   22.89   21.71   34.88   19.40   19.67   21.29   19.65   17.82   14.66   14.73   13.81   11.84   12.02
ENSRNOG00000019918  6.18    6.55    11.05   8.46    11.59   8.41    10.20   10.97   9.41    11.11   7.97    11.92   11.00   12.75   11.32   9.02    9.71    10.90
ENSRNOG00000019921  2.11    2.58    3.77    1.12    3.38    2.78    3.64    3.70    2.32    6.07    1.69    3.90    1.34    1.37    0.66    1.08    1.49    0.77
ENSRNOG00000019922  2.08    1.59    2.09    4.87    2.60    4.27    2.92    3.29    2.27    3.95    4.58    3.52    3.11    3.73    3.47    3.24    1.80    2.88
ENSRNOG00000019924  2.94    5.08    3.03    3.64    3.82    2.08    2.15    3.80    1.62    1.93    1.99    1.90    2.17    2.20    1.70    1.36    1.25    1.98
ENSRNOG00000019926  0.60    0.00    3.91    1.86    0.31    1.48    0.95    0.78    1.26    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.40    0.49    0.00    0.00    0.77    0.00
ENSRNOG00000019930  24.01   25.71   31.19   23.96   42.73   31.90   35.17   51.82   33.34   51.71   57.96   47.26   36.49   33.23   38.51   35.54   33.77   32.26
ENSRNOG00000019931  0.66    2.69    0.44    0.27    0.38    0.00    0.16    0.10    0.21    0.80    0.44    0.90    1.44    1.66    1.23    2.03    0.84    1.05
ENSRNOG00000019932  11.58   20.38   24.63   18.75   17.35   19.51   18.48   18.83   22.97   16.83   19.18   21.32   13.55   15.25   13.46   11.14   9.73    17.28
ENSRNOG00000019933  19.67   23.72   24.54   17.04   29.37   22.88   19.77   19.84   14.62   17.64   17.03   20.86   16.27   14.93   12.34   14.27   12.54   13.83
ENSRNOG00000019934  8.29    10.81   17.96   15.28   11.04   15.60   10.85   10.93   17.02   15.46   21.83   16.73   18.59   21.56   26.50   14.97   11.45   19.04
ENSRNOG00000019935  11.10   15.28   18.47   14.15   21.34   15.47   13.22   12.43   12.13   15.22   10.59   12.80   7.82    9.49    7.43    6.10    7.34    7.07
ENSRNOG00000019936  5.70    6.50    7.84    3.52    3.63    7.00    6.73    3.68    7.96    2.21    2.45    4.33    3.00    3.55    2.74    0.99    5.37    1.59
ENSRNOG00000019940  20.40   34.91   24.75   24.96   10.17   13.38   8.10    3.81    5.07    3.51    3.31    4.48    3.81    3.40    2.67    2.12    3.52    5.94
ENSRNOG00000019943  10.61   10.87   10.86   8.60    5.19    6.85    3.65    6.42    7.03    9.65    12.22   8.84    11.72   10.45   12.05   7.63    8.57    10.74
ENSRNOG00000019946  14.68   12.05   18.61   13.71   31.07   19.10   28.09   32.80   31.51   43.54   39.38   31.19   31.73   29.66   29.03   32.51   26.16   25.39
ENSRNOG00000019948  5.52    8.78    7.20    5.03    6.29    5.26    3.74    4.40    4.56    2.81    4.18    4.42    4.51    4.73    4.77    4.52    3.61    4.23
ENSRNOG00000019949  3.09    6.67    3.44    5.96    2.10    3.38    4.70    0.44    1.92    3.73    1.48    2.62    3.83    2.42    3.59    1.56    2.38    2.09
ENSRNOG00000019953  5.58    2.65    4.19    8.63    3.32    5.14    3.91    6.16    7.14    4.32    9.59    6.36    15.62   14.42   12.26   9.44    7.69    11.96
ENSRNOG00000019955  4.35    6.00    5.15    2.77    3.82    4.38    2.41    4.60    2.36    4.87    3.90    3.13    4.79    5.07    6.14    4.81    4.89    5.65
ENSRNOG00000019956  15.69   17.00   18.29   14.84   21.79   12.07   21.01   19.76   20.68   24.00   22.32   25.61   26.53   24.78   22.11   17.75   18.46   21.91
ENSRNOG00000019957  6.18    8.67    11.06   10.22   9.15    10.39   8.09    8.53    8.38    13.60   14.33   13.93   14.04   12.81   14.39   10.22   9.49    15.56
ENSRNOG00000019958  2.28    6.43    4.17    6.14    10.26   2.31    0.14    1.91    0.94    0.00    0.12    0.41    0.18    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.18    0.17
ENSRNOG00000019959  2.39    12.38   0.65    0.60    0.88    0.41    0.70    0.84    0.37    2.18    1.81    1.38    3.31    1.78    2.86    2.81    3.69    2.73
ENSRNOG00000019960  5.37    7.69    9.44    4.61    9.04    7.41    9.66    7.22    5.66    6.41    7.35    8.00    8.19    8.71    5.61    9.04    7.28    7.17
ENSRNOG00000019962  4.92    8.84    7.67    9.59    8.83    8.18    8.43    8.48    5.48    10.31   14.27   11.10   12.11   8.22    10.21   9.32    8.67    10.93
ENSRNOG00000019964  22.38   34.45   44.86   21.99   35.06   24.03   33.92   28.61   20.89   32.03   23.75   30.15   23.83   26.81   25.02   23.56   25.01   25.75
ENSRNOG00000019965  32.90   35.71   42.46   32.09   46.60   32.45   19.69   15.49   11.02   12.74   5.31    6.61    3.00    2.94    2.64    2.29    2.21    3.37
ENSRNOG00000019968  4.47    7.51    11.01   8.22    11.01   10.45   12.02   8.01    7.68    13.17   13.69   13.81   15.09   14.53   14.62   10.52   8.75    11.53
ENSRNOG00000019970  2.65    4.36    5.01    7.44    8.99    8.67    8.03    6.13    12.74   12.75   9.36    12.53   9.93    12.55   12.41   9.41    10.31   18.15
ENSRNOG00000019971  13.66   12.46   13.87   12.79   15.72   12.71   13.53   5.79    10.63   16.62   15.44   16.03   14.55   14.10   15.39   13.63   11.59   13.24
ENSRNOG00000019973  3.05    5.99    4.07    3.77    3.11    2.71    3.03    1.09    1.66    2.62    1.75    1.29    1.85    2.10    1.10    1.60    1.78    0.64
ENSRNOG00000019974  55.85   126.22  78.63   67.14   83.27   67.36   84.72   63.96   44.91   70.99   40.33   56.12   40.35   40.71   44.28   37.90   30.24   50.87
ENSRNOG00000019975  10.46   10.69   15.48   13.62   12.58   13.63   13.70   12.20   13.75   17.90   19.88   16.28   21.25   19.09   18.76   14.38   12.43   18.07
ENSRNOG00000019976  0.30    2.76    1.82    2.25    1.85    2.61    1.59    1.96    2.54    2.34    2.60    4.15    2.80    1.65    2.23    2.55    1.93    1.48
ENSRNOG00000019977  28.10   59.37   28.90   17.76   27.54   20.48   14.68   16.93   17.10   2.79    1.99    1.16    0.47    0.80    0.93    0.73    1.15    0.95
ENSRNOG00000019978  8.24    8.96    10.07   6.93    9.97    8.11    7.22    8.94    7.52    7.23    9.69    7.94    7.06    5.86    6.15    5.76    4.16    5.86
ENSRNOG00000019979  0.94    1.79    1.78    2.20    2.02    3.21    0.88    0.94    1.17    2.27    0.90    3.50    1.16    3.11    2.66    1.34    1.05    2.55
ENSRNOG00000019980  14.51   30.90   20.35   24.24   15.29   22.90   10.68   8.12    9.80    13.49   13.52   13.62   10.54   8.84    8.53    6.95    4.22    9.02
ENSRNOG00000019981  12.15   15.82   17.18   10.26   9.18    13.88   10.52   8.68    11.99   17.05   17.46   15.88   14.82   15.81   14.24   11.93   9.45    14.01
ENSRNOG00000019982  1.84    1.05    2.07    1.14    1.64    0.85    0.72    0.30    0.64    2.49    1.18    0.35    1.24    0.64    0.49    0.54    1.19    1.43
ENSRNOG00000019983  3.37    4.38    6.53    6.05    5.22    5.44    3.55    2.55    3.74    7.93    6.21    4.25    5.55    7.18    8.72    5.40    4.65    5.66
ENSRNOG00000019986  8.53    8.53    12.90   8.49    7.49    14.36   4.83    6.78    8.82    5.50    7.00    7.59    7.68    5.46    7.33    3.41    3.31    5.36
ENSRNOG00000019987  7.35    11.30   14.72   17.79   18.90   19.65   14.78   13.21   10.72   11.88   10.17   14.59   6.31    6.60    5.70    2.68    3.24    3.51
ENSRNOG00000019990  1.30    6.42    2.60    5.35    3.97    2.66    5.46    2.79    6.05    6.03    2.60    7.24    9.16    6.42    3.98    9.31    5.88    4.63
ENSRNOG00000019992  3.09    4.89    4.79    5.39    5.88    5.10    6.50    4.54    4.71    5.22    4.05    5.88    3.73    3.15    3.85    3.38    3.95    3.95
ENSRNOG00000019995  4.58    5.50    8.69    4.47    6.14    6.82    6.46    3.74    3.71    4.48    5.18    8.44    5.74    4.74    5.31    2.60    3.53    4.32
ENSRNOG00000019996  30.05   49.03   56.71   77.01   48.10   73.45   21.18   23.61   25.30   45.44   54.15   73.54   33.70   32.91   54.30   24.21   36.02   44.04
ENSRNOG00000020000  1.19    1.70    4.29    2.09    2.94    2.20    1.15    0.64    1.95    2.93    2.65    3.18    2.07    2.80    4.07    1.68    1.73    3.20
ENSRNOG00000020004  2.92    3.77    3.31    2.09    3.76    3.12    2.59    2.48    3.01    3.22    3.44    3.51    2.36    2.79    2.31    2.42    2.02    2.79
ENSRNOG00000020005  22.01   34.21   30.48   37.65   41.72   36.68   31.67   40.06   30.96   46.67   46.50   43.83   27.76   27.87   26.16   22.52   19.51   26.47
ENSRNOG00000020006  14.51   16.98   22.02   15.07   19.62   19.34   7.50    15.04   10.67   13.42   15.20   11.91   12.65   12.07   14.97   10.50   10.83   13.21
ENSRNOG00000020010  1.73    3.49    3.20    4.45    4.35    3.28    2.24    2.41    1.12    3.09    2.06    1.62    2.48    1.52    2.34    1.38    0.88    1.70
ENSRNOG00000020013  9.35    9.40    7.27    8.22    10.41   8.32    3.23    1.75    1.03    0.19    0.11    0.00    0.25    0.14    0.14    0.20    0.41    0.47
ENSRNOG00000020014  1.48    2.43    3.93    3.15    12.27   8.30    22.05   20.05   16.47   29.33   38.33   30.42   22.18   19.67   17.41   19.23   15.66   12.63
ENSRNOG00000020016  7.66    7.74    10.53   10.57   8.04    7.00    11.05   5.37    5.51    8.14    8.29    12.66   8.86    13.42   9.41    10.42   8.81    11.22
ENSRNOG00000020020  7.79    13.48   12.88   10.77   17.43   17.30   20.82   15.35   14.78   42.35   40.08   64.23   24.95   32.55   26.76   25.03   21.72   34.28
ENSRNOG00000020022  5.50    7.48    9.19    6.81    7.22    9.35    4.41    7.79    5.13    2.03    2.93    2.39    3.85    1.88    4.46    2.43    1.01    1.62
ENSRNOG00000020024  3.19    3.94    2.82    4.58    3.13    2.98    3.76    1.32    2.50    3.36    2.53    4.47    5.20    4.95    4.91    3.36    2.20    4.08
ENSRNOG00000020025  5.37    2.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    3.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    4.39    0.00
```

What I am doing in R is:

```
d=read.table("data.txt", header=T, sep="\t", row.names=1)
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(circlize)
mat=as.matrix(d)
base_mean = rowMeans(mat)
mat_scaled = t(apply(mat, 1, scale))
type = gsub("T\\d+_", "", colnames(mat))
head(type)
Heatmap(mat_scaled, name = "expression", km = 7, col = colorRamp2(c(-2, 0, 2), c("blue","white","red")), top_annotation = ha, top_annotation_height = unit(4, "mm"), show_row_names = FALSE, show_column_names = FALSE)
```

What I aim is to get only the genes that are significantly different for each group. for example, the high expressed genes only in G1 group, G2, G3 .... and so on, should only be plotted with some p-value cut-off.

How and at which step I should induce this filter and could anyone please help me in creating such a filter.